# How to remove Series name on bottom and we are not getting bar value on top of each bar and also each bar description is aligned cross in Columnchart

Tags: android, charts, highcharts

```
val chartView = holder.hcopbar
        chartView.addFont(R.font.nsregular)

        chartView.plugins = ArrayList(Arrays.asList("drilldown"))

        val options = HIOptions()

        val chart = HIChart()
        chart.type = "column"
        chart.backgroundColor = HIColor.initWithHexValue("F2F9FC")
        options.chart = chart

        val title = HITitle()
        title.text = ""
        options.title = title

        val credits = HICredits()
        credits.enabled = false
        options.credits=credits

        val export = HIExporting()
        export.enabled=false

        options.exporting = export



        val xAxis = HIXAxis()
        xAxis.type = "category"
        options.xAxis=ArrayList(listOf(xAxis))

        val yAxis = HIYAxis()
        yAxis.title = HITitle()
        yAxis.title.text = ""
        yAxis.visible = false

        options.yAxis=ArrayList(listOf(yAxis))


        val plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
        plotOptions.series = HISeries()
        plotOptions.series.dataLabels = ArrayList<Any>()
        options.plotOptions = plotOptions


        val tooltip = HITooltip()
        tooltip.headerFormat = "<span style=\"font-size:11px\">{series.name}</span><br>"
        tooltip.pointFormat =
            "<span style=\"color:{point.color}\">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>"
        options.tooltip = tooltip

        val columncolors = ArrayList<String>()
        columncolors.add("#FBB519")
        columncolors.add("#F5716F")
        columncolors.add("#00B9C4")
        columncolors.add("#ABC22A")
        columncolors.add("#CA56AF")
        columncolors.add("#CA56AF")

        val series1 = HIColumn()
        series1.name = ""
        series1.colorByPoint = true
        series1.colors = columncolors



        val map1: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map1["name"] = "Hyderabad"
        map1["y"] = 56.33
        map1[""]
        map1["drilldown"] = "Microsoft"

        val map2: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map2["name"] = "Vijayawada"
        map2["y"] = 24.03
        map2["drilldown"] = "Chrome"

        val map3: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map3["name"] = "Secundrabad"
        map3["y"] = 18.38
        map3["drilldown"] = "Firefox"

        val map4: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map4["name"] = "Kakinada"
        map4["y"] = 14.77
        map4["drilldown"] = "Safari"

        val map5: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map5["name"] = "Nellore"
        map5["y"] = 21.50
        map5["drilldown"] = "Opera"

        val map6: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        map6["name"] = "Kurnool"
        map6["y"] = 30.00
        map6["drilldown"] = "null"


        val series1_data =  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>()
        series1_data.add(map1)
        series1_data.add(map2)
        series1_data.add(map3)
        series1_data.add(map4)
        series1_data.add(map5)
        series1_data.add(map6)


        series1.data = ArrayList(series1_data)
        val series = ArrayList<HISeries>()
        series.add(series1)
        options.series = series



        val drilldown = HIDrilldown()

        val series2 = HIColumn()
        series2.name = "Hyderabad"
        series2.id = "Microsoft"

        val object1 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter1", 24.13)
        val object2 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter2", 17.2)
        val object3 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter3", 8.11)
        val object4 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter4", 5.33)

        val series_list = ArrayList<Any>()
        series_list.add(object1)
        series_list.add(object2)
        series_list.add(object3)
        series_list.add(object4)

        series2.data =
            ArrayList(series_list)

        val series3 = HIColumn()
        series3.name = "Vijayawada"
        series3.id = "Chrome"

        val object5 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter1", 24.13)
        val object6 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter2", 17.2)
        val object7 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter3", 8.11)
        val object8 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter4", 5.33)

        val series_list1 = ArrayList<Any>()
        series_list1.add(object5)
        series_list1.add(object6)
        series_list1.add(object7)
        series_list1.add(object8)

        series3.data =
            ArrayList(series_list1)

        val series4 = HIColumn()
        series4.name = "Secundrabad"
        series4.id = "Firefox"

        val object9 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter1", 24.13)
        val object10 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter2", 17.2)
        val object11 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter3", 8.11)
        val object12 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter4", 5.33)

        val series_list2 = ArrayList<Any>()
        series_list2.add(object9)
        series_list2.add(object10)
        series_list2.add(object11)
        series_list2.add(object12)

        series4.data =
            ArrayList(series_list2)


        val series5 = HIColumn()
        series5.name = "Kakinada"
        series5.id = "Safari"

        val object13 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter1", 24.13)
        val object14= arrayOf<Any>("Quarter2", 17.2)
        val object15 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter3", 8.11)
        val object16 = arrayOf<Any>("Quarter4", 5.33)

        val series_list3 = ArrayList<Any>()
        series_list3.add(object13)
        series_list3.add(object14)
        series_list3.add(object15)
        series_list3.add(object16)

        series5.data =
            ArrayList(series_list3)


        val seriesList = ArrayList<HISeries>()

        seriesList.add(series2)
        seriesList.add(series3)
        seriesList.add(series4)
        seriesList.add(series5)



        drilldown.series = ArrayList(seriesList)
        options.drilldown = drilldown

        chartView.setOptions(options);
```

[placing column values on top of each column in orange marked places and need to remove series name as it has in green marked circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgKne.jpg)

Above is my code from that i got output as in that attached screenshot and my requirements are :

1. i need to remove Series name on bottom of the chart.
2. Each bar should show its value on top of the each bar.
3. Each bar description text is aligned cross vertically and i need to make it as flat aligned text.

Kindly help me in meeting my requirements.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solutions are as below:-

1.`

```
var legend = HILegend()
legend.enabled = false
options.legend = legend
```

`

2.`

```
val plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
   plotOptions.series = HISeries()
val dataLabels = HIDataLabels()
            dataLabels.format = "{y}"
            dataLabels.enabled = true
            dataLabels.color = HIColor.initWithHexValue("#F2F9FC")
            plotOptions.series.dataLabels = arrayListOf(dataLabels)
           // plotOptions.series.dataLabels = ArrayList<Any>()
            options.plotOptions = plotOptions
```

`

3.`

```
    val xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.type = "category"
    xAxis.labels = HILabels()
    xAxis.labels.enabled = true
    xAxis.labels.rotation =0
    xAxis.labels.style = HICSSObject()
    xAxis.labels.style.fontFamily = "nsregular"
    xAxis.labels.style.fontSize = "10px"
    options.xAxis=ArrayList(listOf(xAxis))
```

`

Comment: I have found answer and updated as above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).